# Error message after rebuild index

Tags: orchardcms

I have a content type consiting out of two fields "First" and "Second". Then I said "Include in Index". After going to the settings and clicking "Rebuild Index" the following message occurs:
(I am using SQL Express with Orchard 1.8.1)

> Oops. Something went wrong ... sorry
>
> An unhandled exception has occurred and the request was terminated.
>   Please refresh the page. If the error persists, go back Access to the
>   path 'segments.gen' is denied. System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access to the path 'segments.gen' is denied. at
>   System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath,
>   Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound) at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost) at
>   Orchard.Indexing.Services.IndexingTaskExecutor.DeleteIndex(String
>   indexName) at
>   Orchard.Indexing.Services.IndexingTaskExecutor.RebuildIndex(String
>   indexName) at
>   Orchard.Indexing.Services.IndexingService.RebuildIndex(String
>   indexName) at
>   Orchard.Indexing.Controllers.AdminController.Rebuild(String id) at
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41()

The search settings page is empty now:
[image: search settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the folder permissions for Orchard.Web\App_Data\Sites\Default\Indexes\Search and C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Orchard1\App_Data\Sites\Default it worked. I have to installations one on my development and the other on the test machine. So when I setup everything in Visual Studio somethimes folder permissions are not yet correct after publishing to the other system. I just changed IIS_IUSRS to have full access to these folders.

Comment: Per the [Orchard docs](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Manually-installing-Orchard-zip-file#RunningtheSiteUsingIIS), you should give the app pool identity read/write permissions on the entire app_data and media folders. Also, grant the same access to modules and themes directories if you want users to be able to install them via the admin interface.